# REST API Should I return all nested resources when getting resource

Tags: rest

Suppose that I have two endpoints: /users and /users/:id/discussions.
And here are examples of possible responses to `GET /users/1`

1.

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "User1",
    "id": "1",
    "discussions": [<discussionsList>]
  }
}
```

2. 

```
{ 
  "user": {
    "name": "User1", 
    "id": "1" 
  }
}
```

Is it ok by REST principles if `GET /users/1` returns response 2. and have a separate request `GET /users/1/discussions` to fetch discussions sub collection for user or is it not?

Comment: sounds good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok by REST principles if GET /users/1 returns response 2. and have a separate request GET /users/1/discussions to fetch discussions sub collection for user or is it not?

Almost, but not quite.  [REST principles would ask](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven): how does the client know that `/users/1/discussions` is the right URI to use?

If your representation were instead something like:

```
{ 
  "user": {
    "name": "User1", 
    "id": "1" 
  },
  "discussions": "/users/1/discussions"
}
```

then the answer would be easy -- discussions gives you the URI that you need.

Somewhat more common is to have a collection of URI

```
{ 
  "user": {
    "name": "User1", 
    "id": "1" 
  },
  "links: {
    "self": "/users/1",
    "discussions": "/users/1/discussions"
  }
}
```

[application/hal+json](https://stateless.group/hal_specification.html) is one example of a JSON media type that handles links this way.

You can also include [links in headers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288#section-3)

```
Link: </users/1/discussions>; rel="discussions"; anchor="/users/1"
```

---

If you are going to be compliant with RFC 8288, then you would need to choose between using a [registered link relation](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), [registering](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288#section-2.1.1.1) a new link relation, or using an [extension relation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288#section-2.1.2).

The last of these options is most common.  An RFC 8288 compliant extension relation is supposed to be a "URI that uniquely identifies the relation type".  So you might instead see something like:

```
Link: </users/1/discussions>; rel="https://example.org/discussions"; anchor="/users/1"
```

> Reading the RFC 8288, I'm unable to figure out what should rel point to? Could you please explain what's the point of that field? Does it needs to be some URI or not?

The point of the field is that the value tells you what the relationship is between the anchor and the target.

```
Link: </page/1>; rel="first"; anchor="/users/4"
Link: </page/5>; rel="next"; anchor="/users/4"
```

These two relations tell you that /page/5 comes after /page/4, and that /page/1 is the first page in the sequence.

We can use "first" and "next" here because both of those link relation types are registered with IANA.  (To my great surprise, the references for both of these point to RFC 8288; it is probably better to understand them as described in [RFC 5023](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5023)).

But "discussions", the example we are using here, isn't a registered link relation type.  Which means that we need to use a URI.  That URI doesn't need to be an *HTTP* URI, and it doesn't have to be something that can be downloaded.  But a convenient trick is to choose the URI of the document that explains the semantics of the link relation (ie: the text that explains what does

```
Link: </A; rel="https://example.org/discussions"; anchor="/B"
```

*mean*.  So it's probably going to be a link into the documentation of your API, possibly the document that describes the schema of your JSON representations of your information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Reading the RFC 8288, I'm unable to figure out what should rel point to? Could you please explain what's the point of that field? Does it needs to be some URI or not?

Comment: See extension to answer

Comment: So just to confirm that I got it right. When using HAL to include references as response to GET request, does the client needs to provide the links when doing PUT/POST? It seems to me from https://stateless.group/hal_specification.html  that "links" is part of a resource and therefore should be provided on PUT/POST requests?

Comment: The links are part of the representation of the resource, and SHOULD be included in the body of a PUT request if the client intends for them to be there.  Note that the server is still the authority for its own copy of the representation: it can "transform" the representation (for instance, by adding/removing/editing _links).  You just need to be a little bit careful with the meta data in your response to the request; see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4